# Export the drawn shapes as Image in SVG.js

Tags: svg.js

I'm using SVG.js to draw shapes. I want to save the drawing as an image(.png). Any suggestions to do this?

Comment: take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), your question doesn't provide any code or what have you tried

Comment: You can use this: https://github.com/sampumon/SVG.toDataURL
Convert SVG to Canvas and save the image from canvas. You should be able to do this in 10-20 lines of code

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: yeah. I used "save-svg-as-png" library like following, saveSvgAsPng(document.querySelector('.svg_container'), 'diagram.png');                                        where svg_container is the class name of svg element and diagram.png is the name of the file to be saved